# Int error, simple program

Tags: int

```
void setup() {

  absolute(8);
}

int absolute(int v) {
  if (v < 0) {
    return v * -1;
  }
}
```

This method must return a result of type int.

I know this is a very simple program, but we need to do it for school.
I also know that there the abs() function.
Anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: If you send in 8, it won't be less than 0.  So it will never return.

Comment: What does the function return if v >= 0? :)

Comment: Yeah, but it can also be -8 and it will have the same error

Comment: fvu, thanks, that was it, omg, i feel so dumb now hahaha

Comment: No problem - btw next time you have a question, don't forget to add a language tag.

Comment: What's the problem? You should describe your problem in the question, not just the title. What behavior did you observe and what were you expecting? If you got compiler errors, include them here too.